# Is there a way to get a boolean value using 0 and 1 in Athena?

Tags: csv, amazon-athena

I have a CSV file that I want to query using Amazon Athena. The problem I am running into is that there is a boolean value that uses 0 for false and 1 for true. I thought that the Athena SerDe would be able to parse this but the field is coming up as blank when I query the table so it would appear that it doesn't. If there is a way for me to parse 0 and 1 as boolean values in Athena can someone please let me know? I would rather not edit the CSV file itself as it is very large and that would be very time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `CASE WHEN` to evaluate the value and produce the desired output by comparing it to `null` or `0`. For example:

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
      when (id isnull or id = 0) THEN 'FALSE' 
      ELSE 'TRUE' 
   END BooleanOutput 
FROM students;
```

Produces the output:

```
FALSE
TRUE
TRUE
```

Using the source code below or [from this link for live example](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/IVbV0v3).

```
-- create a table
CREATE TABLE students (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  gender TEXT NOT NULL
);
-- insert some values
INSERT INTO students VALUES (0, 'Felipe', 'M');
INSERT INTO students VALUES (1, 'Ryan', 'M');
INSERT INTO students VALUES (2, 'Joanna', 'F');
-- fetch some values
SELECT CASE when (id isnull or id = 0) THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END BooleanOutput FROM students;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`IF`](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/functions/conditional.html#if) function. If your column is called `zero_or_one` you could write this:

```
SELECT IF(zero_or_one, 1) AS true_or_false
FROM …
```

to convert the number 1 to `TRUE` and all other values to `FALSE`. If your column is a string intsead do `IF(zero_or_one, '1')`.